# How do I figure out the span of vectors that are perpendicular to two specific vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am self studying MIT OCW's Linear Algebra course and I am having trouble understanding and solving these type of questions. *These questions were taken from MIT OCW*

I now understand how to solve something like this:

The vectors that are perpendicular to $V=(1,1,1)$ lie on a ____.

So I have $$\begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{matrix}\cdot \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix}=0 \Rightarrow x+y+z=0$$

$$z=-x-y\quad \Rightarrow \begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ -x-y \end{matrix}=x\begin{bmatrix} 1 &  \\ 0 &  \\ -1 &  \end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix} 0 &  \\ 1 &  \\ -1 &  \end{bmatrix}$$

And now I have proven to myself that the vectors that are perpendicular to $\overrightarrow { V } $ are on a 2 dimensional plane.

Now how can I apply this same reasoning to this question?

The vectors that are perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,2,3)$  lie on a ____.

Steps I took:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x &  \\ y &  \\ z &  \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  \\ 1 &  \\ 1 &  \end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow x+y+z=0\quad \text{ and } \quad \begin{bmatrix} x &  \\ y &  \\ z &  \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  \\ 2 &  \\ 3 &  \end{bmatrix}=0\Rightarrow x+2y+3z=0\quad $$

Now I need to solve for two of the variables in these equations in terms of the third in order to write it as a single vector. How do I do this? No actual solution, please. Hints only.

Comment: I don't know the sequence of topics in MIT OCW Linear Algebra, but have you studied cross products yet?

Comment: @mweiss Yes, I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some commentary on your method first:

Matrices don't really multiply the way you're doing it.  That is two column matrices are incompatible for multiplication.  The way you should really be writing it is $$\pmatrix{x & y & z}\pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\ 1}=\pmatrix{0}$$ But even this doesn't generalize the way that we really want it to (described below).  So instead, it'd be better to write your matrix equation as $$\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1}\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{0}$$

The algebra works out exactly as you've described after that point, but it's still important to make sure your initial steps are correct.

---

Now to the actual answer:

You essentially want to simultaneously solve the following matrix equations:  $$\begin{cases} \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1}\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{0} \\ \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3}\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{0}\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}x+y+z=0 \\ x+2y+3z=0\end{cases}$$

Notice that that is equivalent to solving *this* matrix equation:

$$\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 3}\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{x+y+z \\ x+2y+3z} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0}$$

Below is how to solve it from here:

> To solve this, let's do Gauss-Jordan elimination: $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 0\end{array}\right) \sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 0\end{array}\right) \sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 0\end{array}\right)$$ 
>  Which BTW is exactly the same as this set of operations on the system of equations themselves: $$\begin{array}{cc}\begin{cases} x + y + z =0 \\ x+ 2y+3z=0 \end{cases} \longrightarrow \begin{cases} x + y + z =0 \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ y+2z=0 \end{cases} & \text{(Subtract first equation from second)}\end{array}$$ $$\begin{array}{cc} \longrightarrow \begin{cases} x  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -z =0 \\  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ y+2z=0 \end{cases} & \text{(Subtract second equation from first)}\end{array}$$ 
> Therefore our system is equivalent to this one: \begin{cases}x-z=0 \\ y+2z=0\end{cases}  At this point, if we let $z=t$, we have $$\begin{cases} x=t \\ y=-2t \\ z=t \end{cases} \implies \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = t\pmatrix{1 \\ -2 \\ 1}$$

Comment: This problem comes before the lecture and section of the book that covers Gauss_Jordan elimination

Comment: [How GJE works](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/systlin6.htm) *without* matrices.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer See my answer, now.

Comment: I understand what you are talking about in terms of the format I would put my matrices in when I would multiply them, but I was only going by what Gilbert Strang's *introduction to Linear Algebra* teaches. In fact, at the very end of this section (1.2) he mentions that the dot product is usually seen as a row times a column (with no dot). 

Thank you for the explanation. I don't know why I couldn't apply a simple algebra II skill here. It's all much clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Single out one variable from the first equation and replace it in the second. Then you will have one equation involving the other 2 variables and you will be able to express the second variable in terms of the third.

Finally you will be able to express, for example, $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$, and therefore to express the span $(x,y,z)$ in terms of $z$ alone.

Comment: So, $x=y-z\quad and\quad x=(y-z)+2y+3z\quad $ ?

Comment: @cherry_developer You are supposed to end up with Only one equation involving two variables. If you singled out $x$, then that equation should Only involve $y$ and $z$

Comment: @cherry_developer I added some more explanation to the hint

Comment: I think my problem is that I am not able to properly apply my Algebra II skills here. So from what I understand,  I should solve $x+y+z=0$ for $x$ (although it can be for either of the three variables in terms of the other two) and then I get $x=-y-z$. Then I substitute this for the $x$ in the other equation and I get: $-y-z+2y+3z=0$ Am I doing this right?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer You are! So, after your last equation you arrive to $y = -2z$. Now you can go back to the equation $x=-y-z$ and replace $y$ with $-2z$ in order to have $x$ **and** $y$ in terms of $z$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said (in the comments under the original post) that you know about cross products, a very simple approach is to use the fact that the cross product of two vectors is perpendicular to the plane spanned by those two vectors.